# Realm <List> populated but just with one object

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

First time i use Realm, i use it in a Swift Project. I use the last version of Realm 0.96.3.

I got two Realm Models: *Jog* and *Marker*

```
class RealmCurrentRecJog: Object {

        dynamic var id: Int = 0

        dynamic var duration: Double = 0.0
        let markers = List<RealmCurrentRecMarker>()

        // Specify properties to ignore (Realm won't persist these)

        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "id"
        }
    }

class RealmCurrentRecMarker: Object {

    dynamic var order: Int = 0

    dynamic var latitude: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var longitude: Double = 0.0

    dynamic var speed: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var accuracy: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var altitude:  Double = 0.0

    dynamic var time: Double = 0.0
}
```

As you can see in the Jog model i got a `<List>` of Markers and `id` is the primary key. In the Marker model nothing crazy.

So i fill my Realm Models with this function:

```
private func fillDbWithMarker() {

        let saveJog = RealmCurrentRecJog()
        let saveMarker = RealmCurrentRecMarker()

        let jogToSave = self.jogRecorder.getDraftJog()

        saveJog.id = Int(jogToSave.id)
        saveJog.duration = jogToSave.duration

        saveMarker.order = Int((jogToSave.markers.last?.order)!)
        saveMarker.longitude = (jogToSave.markers.last?.longitude)!
        saveMarker.latitude = (jogToSave.markers.last?.latitude)!

        saveMarker.accuracy = (jogToSave.markers.last?.accuracy)!
        saveMarker.altitude = (jogToSave.markers.last?.altitude)!
        saveMarker.speed = (jogToSave.markers.last?.speed)!
        saveMarker.time = (jogToSave.markers.last?.time)!

        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            do {
                try! realm.write {
                    saveJog.markers.append(saveMarker)
                    realm.add(saveJog, update: true)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

And at the end when i look at my Realm Browser the result is that i just got the last marker in my list even if my Marker table is full.
I don't understand where is my mistake .

[image: RealmBrowser]

**Edit**: Here is the code to make it work

```
do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            do {
                try! realm.write {
                    saveJog = realm.objects(RealmCurrentRecJog).last!
                    saveJog.markers.append(saveMarker)
                    realm.add(saveJog, update: true)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fillDbWithMarker` creates a `Jog` whose `markers` list contains a single marker. When it's saved with `Realm.add(_:update:)`, it updates the existing `Jog` with the same primary key so that its properties match the passed-in object's properties. This results in the existing `Jog` object being updated to contain only the single new marker.

If you tweak `fillDbWithMarker` to retrieve the existing `Jog` with the given ID and append the marker to its `markers` list you'll get the behavior you're after.